# List of TimeSpan to String Array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, timespan

I currently have:

```
List<TimeSpan> times = new List<TimeSpan>();
   // ... setup the thousands of times ...
string[] timeStrings = new string[times.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++)
   timeStrings[i] = times[i].ToString("mm.ss");
```

I feel like there **should** be an easy way to do this in LINQ, but I can't find it.  I got close with `times.Select(s => s.ToString("mm.ss").ToArray())`, but it just got the first element.

*Side note: Are there any good LINQ tutorials out there?*

Comment: Check your parentheses. :)

Comment: [101 LINQ samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
var timesAsString = times.Select(s => s.ToString("mm.ss")).ToArray()
```

Comment: Duh... Thanks =)
Because of the "setup times" part, it'll take a couple minutes to test it.

Comment: All answers were correct. all => +1.  Although, it needed to be a multidimensional array in the end, so I had to resort to a for loop... sad...

Answer (score 2):

```
var timesAsString = times.Select(t => t.ToString("mm.ss")).ToArray();
```

Your `ToArray` call is currently on the *string*, not the enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically right, the problem is that your `ToArray` is being called on the string when it should be outside of that (basically a typo);

What you have;

```
times.Select(s => s.ToString("mm.ss").ToArray())
```

what you should have;

```
times.Select(s => s.ToString("mm.ss")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
times.Select(s => s.ToString("mm.ss")).ToArray();
```

Comment: And only the incorrect answer gets an upvote.  The OP wants a collection of strings, not a single string.

Comment: @Dalorzo: That would make no difference. The list is being passed as a parameter to `string.Join` which I think takes an `IEnumerable<string>` so an array or list will work just as well. Thoguh not using either would be more efficient (though still lead to an incorrect answer due to this missing the requirements).

Comment: ...I suppose that was a bit haughty. :D